# How to verify if WebSphere MQ is using SSL?

Tags: ssl, ibm-mq

Is there a command to run, a configuration file to check or a way to check visually in *IBM WepSphere MQ Explorer* if *WebSphere MQ* is using SSL?

**WebSphere MQ Version:**

```
user@server:/ #dspmqver
Name:        WebSphere MQ
Version:     7.0.1.5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! In order for a QMgr to use SSL the channel must have specified a value for `SSLCIPH`.  If the channel has something specified in `SSLCIPH` then the channel will not run without SSL.  Just display the channel definition and look in the `SSLCIPH` field.  If it isn't blank and the channel is running, it is using SSL.

(*Note:  MQ uses TLS, really.  It has never used SSL.  It has always used TLS but allowed SSL ciphers to run under TLS.*)

However, this doesn't mean that any other channel is using SSL.  Any channel that does not have a value for `SSLCIPH` will run without SSL even if one or more channels **do** specify a value.  Since MQ listeners are promiscuous, the remote QMgr or app can request to start any channel.

For this reason, when enabling a QMgr to use SSL, it is necessary to either make sure *all* channels use SSL or else use `CHLAUTH` rules to make sure the non-SSL channels aren't started by the remote node that is expected to use SSL.

If the SSL channel also specifies `SSLCAUTH(REQUIRED)` (which   is the default) then the client or remote QMgr will be required to present a certificate for the local QMgr to validate.  In that case if you display the channel status the Peer Name fields will contain a non-blank value.  this is called Mutual Authentication.  When using mutual auth be sure to use the `SSLPEER` or `CHLAUTH` rules to specify by distinguished Name which certificates are allowed to connect.

FYI - Version [7.0.1 of MQ is going out of support](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/support/lifecycle/index_w.html) in September 2015.

***UPDATE per comments***
To see the channel attributes or status, use WMQ Explorer or the `runmqsc` command.  The `runmqsc` command can be used interactively or in scripts.  To run it interactively just type `runmqsc [qmgr name]` and then enter the commands you want.  In this case, they would be `DIS CHL([channel name]) SSLCIPH SSLCAUTH` for the channel definition or `DIS CHS([channel name]) SSLCIPH SSLCAUTH` for the channel status.

*(Substitute the actual channel name where it says `[channel name]`.)*

To do the same thing in a script, try something like the following:

```
echo DIS CHL([channel name]) SSLCIPH SSLCAUTH | runmqsc [qmgr name]
echo DIS CHS([channel name]) ALL              | runmqsc [qmgr name]
```

On non-Windows systems you will need to quote the parms due to the shell special characters:

```
echo "DIS CHL([channel name]) SSLCIPH SSLCAUTH" | runmqsc [qmgr name]
echo "DIS CHS([channel name]) ALL             " | runmqsc [qmgr name]
```

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful. But you never gave me a command to run;-)

Comment: @T.Rob, quick update, SSLCIPH and SSLCAUTH are not in DIS CHS, only on DIS CHL.

Comment: Thanks, Morag.  Updated.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Seems legit.

Answer (score 0):

On AIX OS this works.

**Command:**

```
@:/mq/bin #echo "display chl(fooChannel) all" | runmqsc fooQueueManager| grep SSL
```

**Command Output:**

```
   SHARECNV(100)                            SSLCAUTH(REQUIRED)
   SSLCIPH( )                              SSLPEER( )
```

Since `SSLCIPH` is null then SSL is disabled.

Comment: Just remember, that doesn't imply a running channel will match the static definition.  If the definition is changed after the channel is started, the running channel instance will not change to match it. I have on many occasions seen a client channel with hundreds of connections where some subset were SSL and the rest were not.  If a change is made, make sure to issue a `STOP CHL(...) STATUS(INACTIVE)` after the change is made to force running instances to stop.  Poorly coded apps may not reconnect and need their own restart in that case.